Adding a MUX to create a configurable voltage divider
I've got a circuit that consist of 16 analog inputs connected to a 16:1 MUX, itself connected to a buffering op-amp, connected to the actual analog input of a Raspberry Pi Pico.
The MUX (74HC4067) is here to give me 16 inputs (yes I could have use something like 2x MCP3008).
Now, I'd like to have a configurable voltage divider. I'm looking at replacing my fixed resistor with another 4:1 MUX (TS3A5017, dual channel but that's OK) between the first MUX and the OP-AMP.
So the output of the first MUX goes into the 1D pin of the 2nd one, then the 4 "S" pins each go through a different resistor before being joined and fed into the OpAmp.

(!RMUX0_EN1 is tied to GND)
I'm not building an oscilloscope or any high precision circuitry, and I can't think of anything wrong with the design... did I miss something?
Edit: some more details. Analog signal, less than 10 Hz, current voltage divider uses a 5k resistor, but I'm looking at using photodiodes which are often in the 50k range, so I wanted to be able to improve resolution for them. They might also get in the M range in dark conditions.
Inputs are filtered (RC filter, current limiting resistor, clamping shottky diodes).

While this would work, this sounds like a good use case for what's called a digital potentiometer, provided your photodiode doesn't have to use more than about 5 V bias.

@Hearth Thanks for your comment. The ones I know are SPI or I²C, which got them rules out for this project. Bascially went to create my own one with MUX + restistors. Also for the ones I know, they have preset resistors ("of course"), while here I can change the resistors as I wish (even if manually). I don't believe I ever came across a non I²C/SPI digital POT, if you have a reference I'm interested!

Here's digikey's catalog of digital potentiometers filtered to show only ones that support simple interfaces (I assume if I²C and SPI are out of the question, then 1-wire and other serial protocols are as well). These are either parallel or have "up" and "down" pins that increment/decrement the wiper position on every pulse.

@Hearth Thank you very much, especially in hindsight I could have done this myself. For some reason I had in the corner of my head I had done such a search already and failed at finding anything outside of SPI/I²C.

Yes a MUX would work. Make sure that your signals do not hit the rails .Now if you use resistors that are low like say 600 ohm then the on resistance of the chip will add to your error budget .The on resistance has a lot of spread from device to device and manufacturer to manufacturer so over a sensible temp range you could get a two to one variation .example adding 20 to 40 ohms to 600 ohms gives significant errors. Higher value resistors sort this ,leakage will only become an issue at megohms so 10k to 100k is a good ballpark start .If you are doing high frequencies like MHz then look carefully at the capacitance and its error budget .You may have lower resistor values that you would want for DC .

Can you elaborate on leakage? My chosen values are 5k, 10k, 100k, 1M.

You will be just fine with your values at low freq
